# SQL Syntax - Section in MERGE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It's been a while since I've worked in a T-SQL environment. I previously worked for Google, and, of course, they had their own special flavor of SQL. Now that I'm back, I'm reading back up on my T-SQL features.

I understand the MERGE statement (at least, I think I do!), but I was looking at examples, and I saw one that had some syntax in it that I'm not familiar with:

From MSDocs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Production.usp_UpdateInventory  
    @OrderDate datetime  
AS  
MERGE Production.ProductInventory AS target  
USING (SELECT ProductID, SUM(OrderQty) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod  
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh  
    ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID  
    AND soh.OrderDate = @OrderDate  
    GROUP BY ProductID) AS source (ProductID, OrderQty)  
ON (target.ProductID = source.ProductID)  
WHEN MATCHED AND target.Quantity - source.OrderQty <= 0  
    THEN DELETE  
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET target.Quantity = target.Quantity - source.OrderQty,
                    target.ModifiedDate = GETDATE()  
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.ProductID, Inserted.Quantity,
    Inserted.ModifiedDate, Deleted.ProductID,  
    Deleted.Quantity, Deleted.ModifiedDate;  
GO  
  
EXECUTE Production.usp_UpdateInventory '20030501'
```

I'm most interested in the following line:
`GROUP BY ProductID) AS source (ProductID, OrderQty)`

What's going on in those second parentheses? It looked like column aliasing to me, but it seems to not work in the contexts I would expect it to work in (SQL Server 2019).

Comment: `USING (<DERIVED TABLE>) AS <DERIVED TABLE ALIAS>(<DERIVED TABLE COLUMN NAMES)`

Comment: The last part `(<DERIVED TABLE COLUMN NAMES>)` can be different than columns mentioned in `<DERIVED TABLE>` originally if the `<DERIVED TABLE>` is a sub query as in OP's question

Comment: Thanks for the responses, both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also never did this but just tried assuming this is just about providing alias to the `USING` clause and its columns which further will be used while evaluating `MATCHED` and `NOT MATCHED` conditions.

Lets say  you have ,

```
MERGE Production.ProductInventory AS target  
USING (SELECT ProductID, SUM(OrderQty) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod  
         JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh  
           ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID  
          AND soh.OrderDate = @OrderDate  
       GROUP BY ProductID) AS source (ProductID, OrderQty)
........
........
```

Here `source` is alias to the `USING` clause and `ProductID` is alias to the column `ProductID` mentioned in the select statement of `USING` clause and similarly `OrderQty` is alias to the column `SUM(OrderQty)`.

This can also be written as

```
MERGE Production.ProductInventory AS target  
    USING (SELECT ProductID as ProductID, SUM(OrderQty) as OrderQty 
             FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod  
             JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh  
               ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID  
              AND soh.OrderDate = @OrderDate  
           GROUP BY ProductID) AS source
    ........
    ........
```

As per my observation if we give the alias names at end as in your case `AS source (ProductID, OrderQty)` the columns present within `( )` are assigned aliases sequentially to the columns mentioned in select clause.

Not providing an alias to any column which is using some kind of function will lead to error also.

I have played around with [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3eb0da84bf8b25ea00d989153648d51a) which you can take a look also.

P.S. This kind of syntax we also use with CTE also which you might have come across

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I figured it was something like this, but I couldn't seem to figure it out. I tried aliasing columns like this in a normal query, and it didn't work. And no, I haven't seen this syntax in CTEs -- I've always just explicitly aliased my columns using AS. I think I like this better for certain circumstances, though, as it provides a nice, neat list of column names at the end of the subquery.